# ¿ LA INTERFAZ E MI APP SE PONE LENTA CUANDO SE PORDUCE UNA EXCEPCION?

Tags: java, android-studio, hilos, socket

estoy desarrollando un app que utiliza sockets para comunicarse con una pc y enviar ordenes hasta ahí todo correcto , estoy tratando de controlar algunas excepciones como cuando el socket de la pc no se encuentra disponible ( ya sea por que la pc no esta prendida o no se conecto a la red ) pues intendo mostrar un Toast que diga que no hay conexion pero toda la  interfaz se pone lenta durante  unos 5 segundos 
 y luego muestra el toast esto,  sucede  solamente cuando se produce esta excepción, supongo que de alguna forma se interrupe el hilo principal.   aqui adjunto el codigo :

GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO

BOTON QUE LLAMA A EL EVENTO

```
imageViewAdelante.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    estadoMovimientoCallable="w";
                    FutureTask task = new FutureTask(new ControlCallable());
                    ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor ();
                     es.submit(task);
                    try {
                        Boolean esta= (Boolean) task.get();
                        if(!esta){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    es.shutdown ();

                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                    estadoMovimientoCallable="o";
                    FutureTask task = new FutureTask(new ControlCallable());
                    ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor ();
                    es.submit(task);
                    try {
                        Boolean esta= (Boolean) task.get();
                        if(!esta){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    es.shutdown ();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

EVENTO LLAMADO

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import static com.example.dumein.MainActivity.IPCONEXION;
import static com.example.dumein.recusos.recursos.PUERTOCONTROL;

public class ControlCallable implements Callable<Boolean> {
    private Socket socket;
    public static String estadoMovimientoCallable ="";
    public static Boolean estadoComunicacionControlCallable=null;

    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        try{
            socket = new Socket(IPCONEXION,PUERTOCONTROL);
            if(socket.isConnected()){
                estadoComunicacionControlCallable=true;
                DataOutputStream flujoSalida = null;
                flujoSalida = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                flujoSalida.writeUTF(estadoMovimientoCallable);
                flujoSalida.close();

            }else if(!socket.isConnected()){
                estadoComunicacionControlCallable=false;
            }
        }catch (UnknownHostException e1){
            estadoComunicacionControlCallable=false;
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e2){
            estadoComunicacionControlCallable=false;
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        return estadoComunicacionControlCallable;
    }
}
```

Comment: si primero intenta hacer algo y luego suelta el error, es lógico que tu app se congele mientras lo intenta. Podrías poner una animación o algo que mantenga entretenido al user mientras ejecutas ese bloque de código.

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta  yo suponía que no se iba a poner lento ya que estoy ejecutando ese proceso en otro hilo .